# Update a PostgreSQL row with last user and timestamp

Tags: postgresql, trigger, metadata

I would like to track who is the last user who updated the rows of a PostgreSQL table (v9) and when. [This webpage](https://www.dbrnd.com/2016/03/postgresql-update-the-timestamp-column-with-the-use-of-trigger/) explains how to do it with a trigger regarding the timestamp (I did not try it yet), I was wondering if something similar could be done to keep the user name.

Comment: Yes, certainly. Just use the `current_user` function.